# TinyText VS LongText !

Tags: mysql, database

Maybe this is a very stupid question but... Why should I use tinytext and not longtext ?

In tinytext I can save only 255 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more efficient. If you don't need more than 255 chars, use it; if you do, then don't. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @xRobot: Speed and space used (on disk and in RAM). Like I said, if you need more than 255 chars, don't use TINYTEXT; the performance difference is likely not going to be very noticeable. But if the column will only ever hold a maximum of, say, 200 chars, there is no reason not to use TINYTEXT.